# Javascript URL redirect based on input and referenced data?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script that will take the user to a specific page referenced url. A typical page url we use is:

```
http://www.*****.com/Catalogues/Main/2012-Spring-Fall/#/XXX/zoomed
```

So with the below script, when they enter in a page number such as 123, it would replace XXX (from the above url) with 123 and takes you to page:

```
http://www.*****.com/Catalogues/Main/2012-Spring-Fall/#/123/zoomed
```

However, I need to split it into sections as follows:
**Section 01 is pages 001-050**, **Section 02 is pages 051-100** and **Section 03 is pages 101-150**

And the new url becomes:

```
http://www.*****.com/Catalogues/Main/2012-Spring-Fall/Sections/XX/#/XXX/zoomed
```

How can I assign what blocks of page numbers belong to each Section and have that automatically entered when they only enter in a page number so that the landing url will be:

```
http://www.*****.com/Catalogues/Main/2012-Spring-Fall/Sections/03/#/123/zoomed
```

If javascript can't handle this, than perhaps PHP?

Would appreciate any help.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function handleEnter (field, event) {
            var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which :     event.charCode;
        if (keyCode == 13) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < field.form.elements.length; i++)
                if (field == field.form.elements[i])
                    break;
            i = (i + 1) % field.form.elements.length;
            field.form.elements[i].focus();
            return false;
        } 
        else
        return true;
    }      

    </script>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
function goForit() {
var password;
password=this.document.testform.inputbox.value
location="http://www.*****.com/Catalogues/Main/2012-Spring-Fall/#/" + password + "/zoomed/" 
}
// End -->
</SCRIPT>

    <TABLE WIDTH=200 BORDER=0 align="center" CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0>
    <TR>
    <TD><CENTER>
      <FORM NAME="testform" target="_top">
        Go to page:
      <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" value="" size="3" onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)">
      <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="BUTTON" value="Go!" onClick="goForit(this.form)">
      </FORM>
    </CENTER>
    </TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your best bet might be to create a webservice that can be accessed via AJAX to avoid hardcoding this logic into your JS. Have the user submit the page they want, pass it back to your backend, have your backend respond with the correct URL, redirect to said URL.

Done.